# Using Guava to index fields that can match multi properties

Tags: java-7, guava

We have a collection of plans that we want to index based on 3 properties. Each can have any combination of values, up until now the would only be 1 of the 3. We want to be able to use Guava as that is the companies code standard and therefore I need to do my best to use it for any loops. The Products collection can be very large so we want to reduce the amount of loops if possible. Here is what we have:

```
private static Function<Product, ProductType> TO_PRODUCT_TYPE = 
    new Function<Product, ProductType>()
{
  @Override
  public ProductType apply(Product product)
  {
    if (product.isOne())
    {
      return ProductType.ONE;
    }
    else if (product.isTwo())
    {
      return ProductType.TWO;
    }
    else if (product.isThree())
    {
      return ProductType.THREE;
    }
    return null;
  };
}
...
Multimap<ProductType, Product> productsByType = Multimaps.index(products, TO_PRODUCT_TYPE);
List<Product> oneProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(SINGLE);
List<Product> twoProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(ProductType.TWO);
List<Product> threeProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(ProductType.THREE);
```

However this is works if there is only 1 type for each. Is there a way to index if there are multiple possibilities? eg If Product 1 is both ONE & TWO it would be in both oneProducts & twoProducts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently provided in Guava but you can always copy [`Multimaps.index(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) and create your own `multiIndex(...)`:

```
public static <K, V> ImmutableListMultimap<K, V> multiIndex(
        Iterable<V> values, Function<? super V, ? extends Iterable<? extends K>> keysFunction) {
    return multiIndex(values.iterator(), keysFunction);
}

public static <K, V> ImmutableListMultimap<K, V> multiIndex(
        Iterator<V> values, Function<? super V, ? extends Iterable<? extends K>> keysFunction) {
    checkNotNull(keysFunction);
    ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V> builder = ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        V value = values.next();
        checkNotNull(value, values);
        Iterable<? extends K> keys = keysFunction.apply(value);
        checkNotNull(keys, value);
        for (K key : keys) {
            builder.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

And then you can use it by updating your `TO_PRODUCT_TYPE` to be a `TO_PRODUCT_TYPES`:

```
private static Function<Product, EnumSet<ProductType>> TO_PRODUCT_TYPES =
        new Function<Product, EnumSet<ProductType>>() {
            @Override
            public EnumSet<ProductType> apply(Product product) {
                EnumSet<ProductType> productTypes = EnumSet.noneOf(ProductType.class);
                if (product.isOne()) {
                    productTypes.add(ProductType.ONE);
                }
                if (product.isTwo()) {
                    productTypes.add(ProductType.TWO);
                }
                if (product.isThree()) {
                    productTypes.add(ProductType.THREE);
                }
                return productTypes;
            }
        };
...
Multimap<ProductType, Product> productsByType = multiIndex(products, TO_PRODUCT_TYPES);
List<Product> oneProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(ProductType.ONE);
List<Product> twoProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(ProductType.TWO);
List<Product> threeProducts = (List<Product>) productsByType.get(ProductType.THREE);
```

Note that this will ignore products without a type.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<ProductType, Product> builder =
    ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
for (Product product : products) {
  if (product.isOne()) {
    builder.put(ProductType.ONE, product);
  }
  if (builder.isTwo()) {
    builder.put(ProductType.TWO, product);
  }
  // ...

  // or better, if possible:
  for (ProductType type : product.getTypes()) {
    builder.put(type, product);
  }
}
ImmutableListMultimap<ProductType, Product> productsByType = builder.build();
```